# Giving the console output as return statement Java

Tags: java, methods, return

I am new to coding and I have to code a NxN star grid as assignment. There is a tester program of the professor which gives input and tests the code.
The problem is that we have to write the code as a method and the test gets whatever I put to my return statement as the result instead of the correct output. How can I rearrange the code that the return statement will give me the result?

```
 public class Assignment 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    run(0);
    }
public static int run(int i)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < i; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < i; col++)
                System.out.print("*");
                System.out.print("\n");
        }

        //How can I change the return so that the tester gets the  
        //correct result?

        return ?output?;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the correct output supposed to be?

Comment: If the test input is 2 for instance it is supposed to print a 2x2 square out of *

As;
**\n
**\n

Comment: The return type of the function has to be an `int`. A `NxN` square will never be an int.

Comment: Then how can I rearrange this code? I tried to rearrange it in a way that my method type will be a string and made the return null, then the result was naturally being null :/ Kind of stuck at this point

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, you want to have result in some object to return it. There are many possibilities, for example:

```
public static String run(int size) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            sb.append("*");
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());

    return sb.toString();
}
```

You need to change a return type to String.

Comment: This is good but there are a lot of statements on your solution that we didn't learn yet, the stuff has to be beginners' level :D

Comment: The only new thing is StringBuilder.
Instead of declaring StringBuilder declare a String and than instead of sb.append("character") do myString += "character", and at the end you can return that. It is less effective, but still works.

Comment: I already used string and System.out.print in place of the other things. But what can I use instead of x.tostring()?